How can I create and use a Qt6 Library?
I'm trying to make a Qt6 Library that I can use within other projects. I had this working with Qt5 (using qmake), but I can't seem to get it working with Qt6 (using cmake). It's worth noting that my Qt6 Library Project is in a different folder than the SampleProject trying to use it.

SampleLib Location: C:\Users\ItsAMe\Desktop\QTProjects\SampleLib
SampleProject Location: C:\Users\ItsAMe\Desktop\QTProjects\SampleProject

What am I doing wrong/missing?
SampleLib Project
SampleLibConfig.cmake.in
set(SAMPLELIB_VERSION 1.0.0)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

set_and_check(SAMPLELIB_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@")
set_and_check(SAMPLELIB_SYSCONFIG_DIR "@PACKAGE_SYSCONFIG_INSTALL_DIR@")

check_required_components(SampleLib)

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(SampleLib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick)

add_library(SampleLib STATIC
  SampleLib.cpp
  SampleLib.h
  SampleRect.qml
  SampleLib_global.h
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME} CACHE PATH "Location of header files" )
set(SYSCONFIG_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME} CACHE PATH "Location of configuration files" )

configure_package_config_file(${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
    PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR SYSCONFIG_INSTALL_DIR)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION 1.0.0
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
              ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

target_include_directories(SampleLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(SampleLib PRIVATE
   Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
   Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick)

target_compile_definitions(SampleLib PRIVATE SAMPLELIB_LIBRARY)

SampleLib_global.h
#ifndef SAMPLELIB_GLOBAL_H
#define SAMPLELIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(SAMPLELIB_LIBRARY)
#  define SAMPLELIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define SAMPLELIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // SAMPLELIB_GLOBAL_H

SampleLib.h
#ifndef SAMPLELIB_H
#define SAMPLELIB_H

#include "SampleLib_global.h"

class SAMPLELIB_EXPORT SampleLib
{
public:
   SampleLib()
   {

   }
};

#endif // SAMPLELIB_H

SampleRect.qml
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    color: "purple"
}

SampleProject Project
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(SampleProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(SampleProject
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(SampleProject
    URI SampleProject
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(SampleProject PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.SampleProject
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

set(SampleLib_DIR C:/Users/Ricky/Desktop/QTProjects/SampleLib/Build/Release)
find_package(SampleLib REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(SampleProject PRIVATE ${SampleLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#Issue: Cannot open input file 'SampleLib.lib'
target_link_libraries(SampleProject PRIVATE
   Qt6::Quick
   SampleLib
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS SampleProject
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

// Issue: I'd expect that I can format this as #include "SampleLib/SampleLib.h" (even though SampleLib is one directory above this project)
#include "../SampleLib/SampleLib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   // Unresolved external symbol...
   SampleLib test;

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   const QUrl url(u"qrc:/SampleProject/Main.qml"_qs);
   QObject::connect(
      &engine,
      &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
      &app,
      []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
      Qt::QueuedConnection);
   engine.load(url);

   return app.exec();
}

Main.qml
import QtQuick

// Issue: SampleLib: no such directory.
import "SampleLib"

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SampleRect {
        anchors.fill: parent
        //color: "orange"
    }
}


Since your SampleLib project is static, I would put it in a git repository and use FetchContent to load it as a submodule for your SampleProject project. That is probably the easiest approach.
If that is not an option, you would need to generate a CMake Configuration File in order for your project to find your library.

I’ve never used FetchContent… how do I generate the make configuration file?

Here you have some examples. What FetchContent does is downloading the sources of the the repository you choose and handles it as a submodule of your project, without having to physically copy the repository into your project. I use this frequently with for example GoogleTest.

Here is the CMake page for CMakePackageConfigHelpers.

@AndréLehto Still haven't been able to properly load the library. I'm shocked there isn't a Qt guide on how to do this.... or an easier way.

Well, what you are trying to do has nothing to do with Qt really. It is a CMake issue. Do you mind sharing some more code of what you have tried so far?

@AndréLehto I've updated the code to my latest attempt, and documented areas I'm having trouble with with a comment prefix of "Issue:". Thanks!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your problem seems to be how to reuse your own library in many places.
My suggestion would be uploading your library project to GitHub, and then use
FetchContent to fetch the library to whichever project you want to use it in. This way your library will be used and built together with your main project, and can be "re-fetched" in any project where you want to use it. I've put together a small example on how it works.
I have uploaded a very small library project to my GitHub called workbench. Inside are these files:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

project(workbench VERSION 1.0.0)

# Using INTERFACE for header only library
add_library(workbench INTERFACE)

# Giving scope to files inside library
target_include_directories(workbench INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)

module.h
#include <string>

static std::string RandomVariable = "Hello from module";


From here, I've created a small project in which I include my workbench library. It looks as follows:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

project(tester VERSION 1.0.0)

# Allows us to use FetchContent
include(FetchContent)

# Fetches the repository from GitHub
FetchContent_Declare(workbench
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/andrelehto/workbench.git
    GIT_TAG v1.0.0
)

# Makes the repository available to us
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(workbench)

add_executable(tester main.cpp)

# Link to library from GitHub
target_link_libraries(tester workbench)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "module.h"

int main() {
  std::cout << RandomVariable << std::endl;
}

Notice that module.h is now available to us in our main project.
